# Is the term "very average" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, adverbs, gradability

In general does the phrase "[adverb] average" follow the rules of proper English? For example I asked of the water level of a forest and someone replied that it was "very average for this time of year".

Comment: The answer to this question I asked previously might help you: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/149540/can-something-be-extremely-mediocre

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking about "[modifier] correct" or "[modifier] average"?

Comment: "Very average" as opposed to "only average average"?

Comment: Its intention is to say that it is “very close to the average”

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the syntax *adverb adjective*. It is true that the expression itself does sound a bit strange but I would not consider it incorrect since the adjective *average* can be interpreted as ["usual or typical"](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/average?showCookiePolicy=true). (Not necessary to be interpreted as *"constituting a numerical average"* all the time.)

[image]

*[a search result from [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) for "very average"]*

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd No problem.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so here.  My meatloaf can be very average to intensify that it was neither good nor bad, but that is because my meatloaf is not statistically analyzed (yet).

Since rainfall is measured and there are statistics then adding a modifier like very is weird.   The rainfall is average.  The rainfall is one inch below average.  Average is the dead center, you cannot have very dead center.